# How to configure custom Logger Wrapper?

Tags: java, log4j2

I found that Log4j provides the ability to create your [custom Logger](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html#CustomLoggers). I generated it but it cause `"No Log4j 2 configuration file found"` error. When using the default Logger I didn't have this problem. In resources, I have the log4j.properties file.

I've tried set `-Dlog4j.configurationFile` path to my log4j.properies file and it stops causing that error, but it still doesn't log something.

My log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, file, stdout

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.file.File=log/out.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%m
```

How should look log4j.properites file, when I am using custom Logger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used CustomLogger form [log4j Github examples](https://github.com/apache/log4j/tree/trunk/examples/subclass). It works similar, but it does not have a problem with configuration.